# Require path for src image as variable

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm working on a react project created with the create-react-app.

I've got an array of data objects. One of the properties in the object is an image path. If I put the path directly in the src tag and use require it works.

```
<img src={require(`./../../../assets/images/1425629.svg`)} />
```

If I'm using a variable, what I need to do because the path is coming from the object, I'm getting the following error:

```
<img src={require(`${data.image}`)} />
```

`Error: Cannot find module './../../../assets/images/1425629.svg'`

[More code edit]

This is the basis of my object (made it less complex for here)

```
const data = [
    {
        image: `./../../../assets/icons/1458.svg`,
        title: 'title1',
        description: 'description1'
    },
    {
        image: `./../../../assets/icons/48754.svg`,
        title: 'title2',
        description: 'description2'
    },
    {
        image: `./../../../assets/icons/7548.svg`,
        title: 'title3',
        description: 'description3'
    }
];
```

This container component is passing the right data to a functional component

```
const BlogInfo = ({ id }) => <Info {...data[id]} />;
```

And this is the basis of the functional component

```
const Info = ({ image, title, description }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={require(`${image}`)} />
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

So in the functional component, the following is working

```
<img src={require(`./../../../assets/images/1425629.svg`)} />
```

and

```
import icon from './../../../assets/images/1425629.svg';

<img src={icon} />
```

but the way I want to achieve this (dynamically) isn't

```
<img src={require(`${image}`)} />
```

Comment: please post code, so that all can understand what you have tried so far.

Comment: @akhilaravind, updated my post with more code

Answer (score 0):

The error is because when the react app is hosted then the image path changes to a dynamic value which is relative to the path of your host. This is due to bundling by webpack. So react uses require.context which comes from webpack.

export json and get all your required paths. Then do as follows

```
var cache = [];

function importAll (r) {
  r.keys().forEach((key,index) => cache[index] = r(key));
}    

//path from json
importAll(require.context(path, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
export default cache;
```

cache will be an array of all the images you need

in your img tag do as follows

```
<img src={cache[0]}/>
```

if you already know the path you could just import it as

```
import img from imgPath
...
<img src = {img}/ >
```

Hope this helps