# reactjs - run build errors with svg objects

Tags: reactjs, svg, build

I am trying to build a reactjs project which features a few svg logos.

I've added the svg logo in the component like this

```
    <div className="brand-logo">
      <img className="plus" src={require(`logo/S&N_Plus.svg`)}  />
      <img className="smith" src={require(`logo/S&N_Smith.svg`)}  />
      <img className="nephew" src={require(`logo/S&N_Nephew.svg`)}  />
    </div>
```

and when I do -- npm run build

I get this error

```
λ npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build D:\wamp\www\reactscrollproject\reactscrollproj\my-app2
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

.\src\components\Section.js
Cannot find module: 'logo/S&N_Plus.svg'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install logo/S&N_Plus.svg.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-25T22_47_42_749Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the wrong usage of require, which is attempting to treat logo/S&N_Plus.svg as a namespace/module since you do not specify a relative dir.

where are your svgs stored?

there are different ways to reference static assets if they are stored in public/assets folder.

For example:

using env variables:

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
```

using global constant

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```

using relative imports

```
import logo from './logo.png';
...
return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
```

there are also several helper libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-react for better control/manipulation of your embedded svgs.

Comment: I have images loaded in a similar way too --- <img className="plus" src={require(`logo/S&N_Plus.svg`)}   so I need to change this to <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;

Comment: the images don't load with this -- <img class="plus js-plus-animate" src="/logo/S&amp;N_Plus.svg">

Comment: but my method loads the images from the static folder and renders -- <img class="nephew js-nephew-animate" src="/static/media/S&amp;N_Nephew.96f60bc1.svg">

Comment: if you're trying to access process.env.PUBLIC_URL, make sure this is set in your .env file. if using CRA, this should be already in place. alternatively if you want to use require, specify the relative path from your component too svg file.

Comment: set it via webpack after an eject? -- but shouldn't it work locally and via build?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506166/require-path-for-src-image-as-variable